# Login Button on Navbar going out of Place

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I made a navbar for my application and implemented login button for it but it is shifted towards the right and not displaying properly, i have already tried changing the padding and the margins but that did not help.

[Navbar before login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A84Gy.png)

[Navbar after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvxP5.png)

and i am hiding and showing the div on successful signin. How can i insert it properly, so that it shows up in a decent manner and does not escape out from the right. Also any suggestions on adding any color behind the navbar would be a great welcome.

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  color: #5a5a5a;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
.alignr{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper .container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
#mainCarousel .carousel {
  height: 450px;
  interval: 1000;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
#mainCarousel  .carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
#mainCarousel  .carousel .item {
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #777;
}
#mainCarousel  .carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */
#firebaseui-auth-container{
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-height: 15px;

}


.dropdown-toggle{
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-height: 15px;
}

/* Pad the edges of the mobile views a bit */
.marketing {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}


/* Custom CSS =========================================== */
.navbar-inverse {background-color: #efefef; border-color: #FF5200;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {color: #fff; background-color: #c83a3a;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {background-color: #e4dcd2;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {border-color: #c83a3a;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a{color:#000}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{color:#C83A3A}
a{color:#fff}
a:hover{color:#eee}
.marketing img{max-width:100%}
.carousel-caption {color: #000000;}
.carousel-caption  h1{background-color: #eb4800;color: #fff;display:inline-block;padding:4px 18px; width: auto;-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)';opacity: 0.8;}
.dsc {background-color: #757575;color: #fff;display: inline-block;padding: 4px 18px; width: auto;-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)';opacity: 0.8;}
.highlightSection{padding:28px 0}
.highlightSection img{padding:0 0 28px 0}
.highlightSection .media{background-color: #efefef;border: 1px solid #efefef;color: #939393;padding: 10px;text-align: center;}
.introSection{background-color: #efefef; padding:28px 0}
.brandBtn{background-color: #7db641;}
.btn-default{color: #fff;background-color: #7db641;border-color: #7db641;border-radius:0}
.btn-default.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default, .btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus, .btn-default:active {color: #fff;background-color: #c83a3a ;border-color: #c83a3a ;}
.text-primary-theme {color: #7db641;}
.text-danger-theme {color: #FF007A;}
.carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left,
#myCarousel1 .carousel-control.right, #myCarousel1 .carousel-control.left,
#myCarousel2 .carousel-control.right, #myCarousel2 .carousel-control.left {background: none;color: #057C00;font-size: 3em; width: 6%;}
.itemsTitle{border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;padding: 8px 30px;font-size: 20px;text-transform: uppercase;position: relative;margin-bottom: 20px;text-align:center}
#myCarousel .container{padding:0}
#mainCarousel .carousel .item {height: 450px;background-color: #FFF;}
footer{padding:18px 0; background:#111; color:#fff;}
.marketing{padding:28px 0}
.pageTitle{padding:18px 0; border-top:1px solid #efefef; margin-top:92px; background:#efefef}
.pageTitle h2{padding:0; margin:0}
.bodyInner{padding:28px 0}
.carousel-caption {bottom: 61px;}
.mainTitle {padding: 4px 0;border-top: 1px solid #FF8500;background: #FAFAFA;color: #0C0C0C;text-align: center;box-shadow: 0 0 24px #D5D5D5;}
.cntr{text-align:center}

/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Remove the edge padding needed for mobile */
  .marketing {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-left:  15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-left:  0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="themes/assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <title>Bazinga</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="themes/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="themes/assets/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bazinga</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" >About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="container">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="glogin" onclick="signIn();"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>Sign-In With Google</button>
                </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle welcome" id = "hellow" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu logind">
                    <li><a href="#">My Orders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Address</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Signout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Edit 1: if you want more code then you can see a hosted copy here [link](https://bazinga-urban-bites-6dd10.firebaseapp.com/home)

Edit 2: As suggested by [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6703062/ash) the following code centers it as in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjLtm.png) but it is still off the edge and i also tried margin-right:90px but it did not help.

```
.navbar-right{
margin-right:45px;
line-height:48px;
}
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't show your navbar like the images you've provided, could you create a working example of the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to use Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4?

Comment: You can see a hosted copy here [link](https://bazinga-urban-bites-6dd10.firebaseapp.com/home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
.navbar-right{
margin-right:45px;
line-height:48px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work, [link](https://bazinga-urban-bites-6dd10.firebaseapp.com/home) might help you to know more

Comment: It centered it but it is still off the edge, see Edit 2 please.